# split database record into variables

Tags: python, database, sqlite, split

I have a function to search for a line in a database where id code/name matches and then loads the record

e.g. [(1, 'John', 'Smith', 30)]

I am using python and how can I split this list into individual varaibles

e.g.

```
ID = 1
Firstname = John
Surname = Smith
Age = 30
```

Sorry I am new to this and this is probably very simple to implement.

This is what I have so far:

```
def find():
   cursor = db.cursor()

   searchname = str(input('Enter name of product: '))
   sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = '%s';" % searchname.strip()
   cursor.execute(sql)
   a = cursor.fetchall()


   print(a)
   row = a
```

Thanks for your time in helping :)

Comment: You've tagged this both `mysql` and `sqlite3`. Which one are you using? And, if it's `mysql`, which of the various different Python interfaces for it are you using?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, its with sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `sqlite3`, it has [a nifty row factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects) built in that lets you access the rows as if they were dictionaries, with the column names as keys:

```
# right after connect
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

def find():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    searchname = str(input('Enter name of product: '))
    sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = '%s';" % searchname.strip()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    a = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in a:
        print(row['ID'])
```

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but it's usually what you actually *want*. [Creating variables dynamically is a bad idea](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html). If you really want to, though, the answer is the same as dumping any mapping into the local scope, which you can search for if you must.

---

If you'd prefer attribute-style access (like `a.ID`) to dict-style access (like `a['ID']`), that's pretty simple. (But remember that not every valid SQL column name is a valid Python identifier!)

The most efficient way to do this is probably to create a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) out of the `description`:

```
row_type = namedtuple('row', [col.name for col in cursor.description])
for row in map(row_type._make, a):
    print(row.ID)
```

---

If you're using MySQL, I don't know if any of the MySQL libraries provide the equivalent of `Row`, but it's not hard to build yourself by using the `description` property of a cursor, the same way we build a `namedtuple` out of it. For example:

```
for row in a:
    drow = {cursor.description[i].name: row[i] for i in range(len(row))}
    print(row['ID'])
```

Unlike the special `Row` factory, which is specific to `sqlite3`, `Cursor.description` is required by [the DB-API 2.0 spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: Thankyou, this completely solves what I wanted and is so simple. A much better idea doing it this way than what I thought. Thanks :)